# PHP session from sql query Result

Tags: php, sql, chat

this question might be a little dumb ... 
I am trying to achieve a chat system , in which i get the users from this piece of code ..

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
<?php
//We get the IDs, usernames and emails of users
$req = mysql_query('SELECT id, username, email , Online from users');
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="left"><?php echo $dnn['id']; ?></td>
        <td class="left"><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dnn['id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php if(($dnn['Online'])=="online") {echo'<img src="default/images/online.png" width="10" height="10" align="center" >';} ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

And now , I when the user gets clicked , it goes to pm.php , which i haven't coded yet .

HOW DO I SET THE VARIABLE 'pmid' OF THE USER WHO GOT CLICKED IN THE PREVIOUS PAGE ?

For ex:- I clicked on John , whose id is 4 , i want to save it as pmid in the next page and insert the message into table'pm' where from id = Session id and the to is the pmid . i.e 4 who is john ..

I would like you to explain the concept !

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Standard comment: if you just started learning mysql switch to PDO or mysqli because mysql extention is deprecated. (Means that support for it my be removed in the next php version making your code either unsafe or not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another column to the table like this

```
<td class="left"><?php echo '<a href="pm.php?pmid=' . $dnn['id'] . '">Message this user</a>'; ?></td>
```

Now when you click that link the users id will be a parameter in the url. You can then retrieve that id on the next page with `$_GET['pmid']`

Comment: Well yeah sure you can if you don't need those columns anymore.

Comment: how do i notify if there are new messages in the db ?

Comment: What do you mean? You should ask a new question if it's not part of the original question.

Comment: OH !!! MY ..my .. I Accepted yours first .. and then I scrolled down and Accepted his .. And now I got to know that Only one can be accepted ! I'm really sorry :( ..

Answer (score 0):

Try Your Code here ....

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    //We get the IDs, usernames and emails of users
    $req = mysql_query('SELECT id, username, email , Online from users');
    while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="left"><?php echo $dnn['id']; ?></td>
            <td class="left"><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dnn['id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
            <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?php if(($dnn['Online'])=="online") {echo'<img src="default/images/online.png" width="10" height="10" align="center" >';} ?></td>
            <td class="left"><a href="pm.php?pid=<?php echo $dnn['id']; ?>">Go to Pm page</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

AND on pm.php page

```
echo $_GET['pid'];  //OR echo $_REQUEST['pid'];
```